# How to deserialize types that inherit common base class - with Gson?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, gson, deserialization

I have the following hierarchy:

**RESPONSE**

```
public class Response implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private List<Message> messages;

    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

}
```

**MESSAGE**

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

        @SerializedName("type")
        @Expose
        @MessageType
        private int type;

        @SerializedName("position")
        @Expose
        @MessagePosition
        private String position;

        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public String getPosition() {
            return position;
        }

        public void setType(@MessageType int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public void setPosition(@MessagePosition String position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

}
```

**TEXT -> MESSAGE**

```
public class TextMessage extends Message {

@SerializedName("text")
@Expose
private String text;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

}

**IMAGE -> MESSAGE**

```
public class ImageMessage extends Message {

    @SerializedName("attachment")
    @Expose
    private Attachment attachment;

    public Attachment getAttachment() {
        return attachment;
    }

    public void setAttachment(Attachment attachment) {
        this.attachment = attachment;
    }

}
```

Trying to deserialize Message this way with GSon leads (naturally) to empty fields at `text` or `attachment` fields. *I would like to have a best fit deserialization, which based on response would choose at run time which Message type (i.e. Text or Image) matches most fields to be fulfilled.*

So far the only thoughts I had were:

1 - Use @JsonAdapter -> Didn't work

2 - Create another hierarchy structure to point classes at compile time like:

```
---- Response
   |
    - TextResponse -> List<TextMessage>
   |
    - ImageResponse -> List<ImageMessage>
```

Second option is not really what I want and makes me multiply the number of classes in a way that might get too complicated to apply later maintenance.

Does anyone know a way to handle this problem? Any framework or concepts that could be applied?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use Gson extras `RunTimeTypeAdapterFactory`. Check this example:

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Message> factory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
    .of(Message.class, "type") // actually type is the default field to determine
                               // the sub class so not needed to set here
                               // but set just to point that it is used
    // assuming value 1 in field "int type" identifies TextMessage
    .registerSubtype(TextMessage.class, "1")
    // and assuming int 2 identifies ImageMessage
    .registerSubtype(ImageMessage.class, "2");
```

Then use `GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterfactory(factory)` to use this.

**This just is not found from Gson core library**. You need to [fetch it here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java). You might also find some Maven/Gradle dep from global repo that someone has done but maybe easiest is just to copy this file.

It enables later hacks then if you need to modify its behavior.

Comment: Outstanding answer! Seems exactly what I want. Although I'm not gonna be able to implement the answer right now, I'm going to accept it because makes sense to the expected solution. Hope to check if it's really right in a near future or find out through someone else's comment here.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this with `GodClass` that has all of message types fields.

but you don't use this POJO classes as DTO (Data Transfer Object) in your application.

`Json` is a protocol and not supported `Inheritance` and etc.

In same scenario I implemented this inheritance and hierarchy for DTOs.

PS: DTO in my answer is Models that we pass for example in `Adapter` or an `Activity` and so on.

Comment: I thought about making ``Response`` an abstract class an infer an enum to define only the Message type, but that would help only to avoid recursive calls to cast ``TextMessage``, ``ImageMessage``, etc. Still, not quite sure if this or ``GodClass`` would work. Certainly so far it's not the best option.

Comment: It's that you want! https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/json-with-gson-and-abstract-classes.html but I thought it makes dirty my code. Any way you should cast or detect which type should deserialize!

Comment: Something similar - in the perfect world, there would be an annotation ``@Deserialize(using = TextMessage.class, ImageMessage.class)``. In my case, casting wouldn't be really a problem. I'm gonna try to go with this article, thank you =)